# How to install runtime files of Imported shared library in cmake

Tags: cmake

In my project I use an external library, that is integrated as a shared imported library. This library has some files, which are required at runtime. These files and also the license file should be installed when deploying the application.

The cmake of the imported libarary (MyImportedLibConfig.cmake) looks like this:

```
add_library(MyImportedLib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MyImportedLib PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "3rdparty/MyImportedLib /dev/lib/myimportedlib${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/dev/lib/myimportedlib.lib"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/dev/include"
)
```

My initial approach for installing the files was this (also in MyImportedLibConfig.cmake):

```
# install license file
install(FILES "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/license.rtf" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/licenses/MyImportedLib COMPONENT Runtime)
# install binary files
install(DIRECTORY "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/dev/bin/" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin COMPONENT Runtime)
install(DIRECTORY "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/dev/bin/" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/UnitTests COMPONENT Runtime)
```

This works on my local build, but the paths are not reliable (i.e. they are wrong when doing a package build).

What would be the proper way to handle this in CMake?

[Update]
I have been able to fix the messed up installation paths by avoiding the use of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.

```
# install license file
install(FILES "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/license.rtf" DESTINATION licenses/MyImportedLib COMPONENT Runtime)
# install binary files
install(DIRECTORY "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/dev/bin/" DESTINATION bin COMPONENT Runtime)
install(DIRECTORY "3rdparty/MyImportedLib/dev/bin/" DESTINATION UnitTests COMPONENT Runtime)
```

This is still not perfect, but it does the job.

Comment: Have you seen `install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS)` or `install(TARGETS ... RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)`? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-targets

Comment: By the way, `DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/path` is _**ALWAYS**_ wrong. It breaks the `cmake --install ... --prefix ...` command. Never, ever, read `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in your CMakeLists.txt. Fortunately, all you need to do is rewrite it to `DESTINATION path`.

Comment: Also instead of `DESTINATION bin`, write `include(GNUInstallDirs) ... TYPE BIN`.

Comment: @AlexReinking, thanks for your replies!
As far as I can tell from the documentation, IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS and RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES is meant for binaries, on which my application depends. But in my case it is not only about binary files but also about additional files like license files,...

GNUInstallDirs seems to be interesting, but I will need to restructure the installation directories for using that.